# Install wine + freetype from source -> error: FreeType 32-bit development files not found

Tags: x11, wine

I've downloaded the latest versions of Wine(8.18) and Freetype2(2.13.2) from their main sites to be used at the linux CRUX distribution.

The installation of Freetype went smoothly, I guess! ;-)

```
$ configure
$ make 
# make install
```

The generated files were placed at /usr/local/include/freetype2 + /usr/local/lib/libfreetype...

After installing FreeType, and when I try to configure Wine, the configuration process stops with the following error:

```
**checking for -lfreetype... not found 
configure: error: FreeType 32-bit development files not found. Fonts will not be built. 
Use the --without-freetype option if you really want this.**
```

Also something fishy ... many other items seem to be not found by Wine configure as well ...

```
checking for -lXcursor... not found
checking for X11/extensions/XInput.h... yes
checking for -lXi... not found
checking for XShmQueryExtension in -lXext... no
checking for XShapeQueryExtension in -lXext... no
checking for -lXxf86vm... not found
checking for -lXfixes... not found
checking for -lXinerama... not found
checking for X11/extensions/Xcomposite.h... yes
checking for -lXcomposite... not found
checking for XICCallback.callback... yes
checking for XEvent.xcookie... yes
checking for -lGL... not found
checking for -lGL... (cached) not found
checking for -lOSMesa... not found
```

Am I missing something important?

Thanks for your help!

-Francis

---

In the mean time, I've set:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib
```

But with no avail ...

Comment: Off topic here, but a hint: you need to provide the path to your freetype source files (headers) to the `configure` command.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Sorry if the question is off topic but please can you tell me where should I place this answer to be on topic?

Comment: Here is better place for this question: https://superuser.com/